# Avoid the margin inside pre tag

Tags: html, css

How to avoid the margin inside `pre` tag:

```
<p>Some text</p>

<pre>
    <code>
        Some code
    </code>
</pre>

<p>Some text</p>

<style>
pre {
    background-color: rgb(255,247,229);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

**The current output:**

> [image]

**The desired output:**

> [image]

The current solution is to manually remove the indentation in the markup, like shown below. However, as I understand, it is not the optimal way.

```
<pre>
    <code>
Some code
    </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try changing the default value of `white-space` for `<pre>` tag from `pre` to `pre-line`.

> **`pre-line`** Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Read more about `white-space` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```css
pre {
  background-color: rgb(255, 247, 229);
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<pre>
  <code>
    Some code
  </code>
</pre>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<pre>` (preformatted text) tag captures whitespace characters.

If you really would like to avoid capturing whitespace then perhaps using a `<div>` would work better for you. Otherwise I would recommend preformatting your text.