# HTML why are these two elements not positioned directly on top of each other?

Tags: html, layout, css-position

I am trying to write some HTML code to overlay another element directly on top of a `pre` text block.

The problem is, even the most simple example doesn't seem to align correctly...

```
<div style="position:relative">
<pre style="position:absolute">
hello
</pre>
  <div style="position:absolute">
    world
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the output [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n977d1h8/1/).

The `div` element is rendered above the `pre` element. Why is this happening?

More information on positioning of elements can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pre` tag has a margin of `margin: 1em 0px;` by default so you need to set the margins to zero to override this. Then there is still a small amount of gap after this. This is because of the font. In my example. I have overridden the `font-family` to inherit the `font-family` of the parent so the elements are perfectly aligned. Another thing is, the same vice versa effect can be done for `font-family` for the `div` tag instead of the `pre` tag

```css
pre{
margin:0px;
font-family:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<pre style="position:absolute">
hello
</pre>
  <div style="position:absolute">
    world
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the `div` element "is" rendered above the `pre` element. We are just not able to see it. I added a `border` attribute of css to visualize it because of the "pre margin".

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <pre style="position:absolute">
hello
</pre>
  <div style="position:absolute; border:1px solid red;">
    world
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, you can now add some `css` to shift it a bit and get what you want, like this!!

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <pre style="position:absolute">
hello
</pre>
  <div style="position:absolute; border:1px solid red; top: 7px">
    world
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!!
Also it turns out that the `pre` tag has some default `margin` at the top. To see that check this out!!

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Miraj50/bwtcvLfz/)

So to remove that, easy, put `margin` to 0. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Miraj50/ohv1vsrh/)

Comment: Btw for the margin of `pre` tag, check this out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676687/avoid-the-margin-inside-pre-tag)